# FaceBook ShareLinkContent setImageUrl image is overriden by setContentUrl meta-data image

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am trying to Post the below infromation to FaceBook from Myapp using FaceBook ShareLinkContent class

```
 - link url (using SetContentUrl method)
 - image (using setImageurl method)
 - hashtags (using setHashTag method)
 - and Description
```

as like

```
    ShareHashtag shareHashTag = new ShareHashtag.Builder().setHashtag(hashtag_name).build();
     if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
     ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(selectedImagePath))  
                    .setShareHashtag(shareHashTag)
                    .setContentDescription(textd)
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(linkUrlPath))
                    .build();
                    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
           }
            } else {
               shareImage();
              }
```

The question is, instead of posting the image from "selectedImagePath" url, it post the meta-data image coming from the "linkUrlPath" url.

How to overcome it, so that i can post the image which i send in the method `setImageUrl()` method.

note: I am using Facebook SDK 4.14.1

Kindly provide suggestions

Comment: just have a look at it http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what you are looking for - 
[Template Matching](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)

Template Matching is a method for searching and finding the location of a template image in a larger image. OpenCV comes with a function matchTemplate() for this purpose. It simply slides the template image over the input image (as in 2D convolution) and compares the template and patch of input image under the template image.

Comment: Hi Vadiraja, I have tried using the Template matching approach, due to image size different, i am not getting the result as expected.

Comment: Is there any other way to proceed further, provide directions..

Comment: Please, elaborate. Right now, this is a [link-only answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, unfortunately template matching isn't scale invariant. So you will have to look at scale invariant matching algorithms or go for running template matching by re-sizing your original image multiple times.